# JINJA write list object of ansible vars as same representation

Tags: ansible, yaml, jinja2

I have no solution to write object list of my ansible vars (YAML) with JINJA2 templating

See my list example, i dont know key in advance and values could be boolean, list, object, string, integer

```
inputs:
- key1: "val1"
  key2:
    - "val2"
  key3:
    key3.1: "val3.1"
    key3.2: "val3.2"
  key4:
    key4.1:
      key4.1.1: "val1.1"
```

Is it possible to write my YAML list object as the same representation in my vars.yml with JINJA2 by browsering inputs so :

```
inputs:
- key1: "val1"
  key2:
    - "val2"
  key3:
    key3.1: "val3.1"
    key3.2: "val3.2"
  key4:
    key4.1:
      key4.1.1: "val1.1"
```

I already tried many solutions with loop, but I need recursivity i think to write in same representation
It's for automation deployment for filebeat solution with the inputs configuration

Comment: "_Is it possible to write my YAML list object as the same representation in my `vars.yml` with Jinja2_", do I interpret that correct, you have already a file `vars.yml` with the expected content and like to create a copy of the file (content) with Ansible Jinja2 Templating? Wouldn't than just copying it not enough?

Comment: Cause I have some other variables in this file. Moreover it's a general problem to write a dictionary variable in jinja by eventually browsing it recursively. But true, if i have only this vars, i could copy its content in my file. But filebeat configuration could be very long with 4000 lines so it's better to use recursive loop

Comment: "_Moreover it's a general problem to write a dictionary variable in Jinja by eventually browsing it recursively._", I think it is not that simple and general because one would need to write a kind of parser for export. Test in example `from_yaml` or `to_nice_yaml` filter, see also [Ansible: How to fix to_nice_yaml output quotation?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65143189/6771046). In my tests I could easily export as well reimport, but non of my approaches would fulfill your requirement "as the same" ...